# Job offered, interview done, salary offered, how to follow up?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation, internship, follow-up

I recently applied for a paid internship position at one of the banks in my country. The HR rep called me and scheduled me for an interview. I did the interview and the next day they offered me the salary (well not salary, more like an internship allowance).  They checked if that's okay with me, to which I replied yes, I liked the allowance.

The HR rep then told me that she'll talk to the finance dept in regards to when should I start. She didn't specify the exact date but I figured it won't take more than a day since it's only talking to other dept. Well it's been 3 days and I have not received any updates. Should I follow up and ask politely about the timeline decision (when should I start?), or should I just wait it out? I'm really paranoid about this sort of stuff and it's my first time experience as far as job offer is concerned.

And one more question, is it a good idea to follow up on job offer in weekends like Saturday or Sunday?

Answer (score 10):

> She didn't specify the exact date but I figured it won't take more
>   than a day since it's only talking to other dept.

There's your mistake.

Instead, you should have ended the conversation with something like "What are the next steps?" and if it wasn't mentioned "When can I expect to hear back from you?"

> Well it's been 3 days and I have not received any updates. Should I
>   follow up and ask politely about the timeline decision (when should I
>   start?), or should I just wait it out?

Now you need to follow up and get these questions answered.

If you haven't heard within a week, call and ask.

> And one more question, is it a good idea to follow up on job offer in
>   weekends like saturday or sunday?

This is business. And unless this company conducts business on weekends, you should follow up on a weekday. In most companies, HR seldom works on weekends, so you are unlikely to get your answers then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Joe, yeah it was a mistake on my part and I might have to follow up on monday.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, its wrong to assume that the work involving two different departments would be done quickly. Everything in industry follows a process and this takes time. So, I would suggest just relax. Its normal.

Regarding follow-up, just send an email to the HR person you talked to. Monday morning would be a good time to do it so that its on top of her inbox! Just make a polite request about the status of your application/contract.

Additional advice: If there is significant delay and if you already know the person who is going to be your internship supervisor it is wise to involve him. I myself had this experience where the HR took ages to respond and I requested my supervisor to look into the matter. As expected, things moved faster thereafter.